# Visual Studio 2008 -- inserting data in table using VB.Net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I have **visual studio 2008**. I am using vb.net to add data to table in the in-built sql server. I am unable to add data to multi-column tables. I can add data to single column tables but if I add more columns to the table and then associated textboxes to the form, the code throws **"Column name or number of supplied values does not match to table definition"** error.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow @Shweta. Your question still not clear. you should provide some code of what u have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

If u going to execute insert query then you must have specified values for each column.

For example

```
Insert Into TableName (Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4)Values(1, 'Value1', '2014-01-01', NULL);
```

if the number of values and number of specified column does not match then sql will shows the error like **"Column name or number of supplied values does not match to table definition"**

if you are joining values from textbox to your query then you must have specified `NULL` value if textbox is blank or specify default value

```
Dim _SQL As String = string.Empty
_SQL = "Insert Into TableName (Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4)Values("
IF TextBox1.Text != String.Empty Then
    _SQL = TextBox1.Text + ","
Else
    _SQL = "NULL,";
Else

''Continue for second value
```